# preg_split with PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE flag still delimiter gets consumed

Tags: php

String $uri:

```
/profile/asd/
```

I run this on the string:

```
$uri_arr = preg_split('/\//',$uri,-1,PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => profile [1] => asd )
```

I thought PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE was supposed to conserve `/` if not I would use explode instead...

Comment: What did you expect to get? `['/profile', '/asd']`?

Comment: @Jack I expected: If this flag is set, parenthesized expression in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.

Comment: Sure, but they're not parenthesised are they? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the delimiters, you still need to wrap them into parentheses:

```
preg_split('~(/)~', '/profile/asd/', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
```

Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "/"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "profile"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "/"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "asd"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "/"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :)I was thinking it should have been parenthesised in the original string, and couldn't make the sense of it :)